# SQL Injection & General SQL - How does this work?

Tags: php, sql, database, security, sql-injection

I have been reading a PDF (and around the web in general) on SQL Injection and want to make sure of my understanding (it's here if anyone was wondering: http://www.imperva.com/docs/WP_SQL_Injection_Protection_LK.pdf).

If a website expects a username and a password and will selected and display columns based on the query:

"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=' **".$userlogin."** ' AND password=' **".$password."** '"

Then what could the possible SQL injections on this be and what would they do?

1) For example would the following injection obtain all columns for all users?

"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=' **any name** ' AND password=' **any' OR 'test'=test** '"

2) Would the following injection do something, if anything?

"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=' **name' OR 1=1 #** ' AND password=' **any** '"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Would authenticate a user as 'test'='test' and thus would always return true

2) Will authorize the user regardless of the password as [# starts a comment same with --](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html)

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=' name' OR 1=1-- AND password = 'any'`

The idea is the malicious user can continue the query where you left off and do whatever he/she wishes from then on which of course could be just bypassing authentication but also:

[LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) (allows reading files on the remote host)

[INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) (allows writing files on the remote host often with the easily obtainable goal of RCE).

[UNION SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) (usually used when dumping information from the database)

None of these will work without the correct permissions this is why it's incredibly important to not use the root/dba account for anything other than local administration and creating accounts for each individual use with permissions tailored to that use's needs so that, much like users on a computer, one user may not touch another user's things.

Comment: # is a comment sign in MySQL, anything afther the # will be ignored

Comment: @JasonSec How does the first one work? How does it define the user as user as 'test'='test'? Would it not still return the info for one user as it's the password OR true?

Comment: @mino AND/OR statements in SQL work on a boolean basis if it's true data is retrieved.


`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='admin' AND password='$userinput'`



will always fail unless the correct password is given because password will not equal $userinput.

With SQL injection we're simply cancelling that out with an OR so if the password is $userinput(false) OR 1=1(true) then grab this info.

Comment: @JasonSec Would the second one with the comment also return data for all users IF the name wasn't in the database since there is an OR TRUE after it?

Comment: Yes, the OR is across the whole query so regardless of the query if there's an OR TRUE all data will be returned.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=2 AND 2=3 AND 4=5 OR 5=5` would still return true :)